# Different layouts for phone and tablet (1 | 2 columns)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, adaptive-design

I am trying to have a different layout during runtime depending of the hot device phone or tablet.

I'd like to have a 2 columns layout on a tablet and keep a one column layout on a phone.

I'd like also to have some controls to span on 2 columns when on table device, while on phone device the layout should be single column, I mean with many elements to show (3/4 full page height...).

Expected layout:

[image: expected layout]

Comment: You could use a FlexLayout although you wouldn't have precise control. I would probably build the layout in the code behind using a runtime check of the Idiom.

Comment: Another idea would be to specify your pages in separate XAML files then load the correct one at runtime using the same Idiom check idea. Although this could be hard to maintain and unless you abstract all your components into Content Views there may be a lot of duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by taking advantage of `OnIdiom`, here is a sample in xaml: (note also the new simplified syntax for `ColumnDefinitions` and `RowDefinitions`)

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="*,*,*,*,*,*,*,auto"
      ColumnDefinitions="50*,50*">

<BoxView BackgroundColor="Red"
             Grid.Row="0"
             Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

    <BoxView BackgroundColor="YellowGreen"
             Grid.Row="1"
             Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="{OnIdiom Phone=2,
                                       Tablet=1}"/>

    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Aqua"
             Grid.Row="{OnIdiom Phone=2,
                                Tablet=1}"
             Grid.Column="{OnIdiom Phone=0,
                                   Tablet=1}"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="{OnIdiom Phone=2,
                                       Tablet=1}"/>

    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Bisque"
             Grid.Row="{OnIdiom Phone=3,
                                Tablet=2}"
             Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Purple"
             Grid.Row="{OnIdiom Phone=4,
                                Tablet=3}"
             Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="{OnIdiom Phone=2,
                                       Tablet=1}"/>

    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue"
             Grid.Row="{OnIdiom Phone=4,
                                Tablet=3}"
             Grid.Column="{OnIdiom Phone=0,
                                   Tablet=1}"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="{OnIdiom Phone=2,
                                       Tablet=1}"/>

    <BoxView BackgroundColor="DimGray"
             Grid.Row="{OnIdiom Phone=6,
                                Tablet=4}"
             Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="{OnIdiom Phone=2,
                                       Tablet=1}"/>

    <BoxView BackgroundColor="HotPink"
             Grid.Row="{OnIdiom Phone=7,
                                Tablet=4}"
             Grid.Column="{OnIdiom Phone=0,
                                   Tablet=1}"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="{OnIdiom Phone=2,
                                       Tablet=1}"/>
</Grid>
```

**Phone**

[image]

**Tablet**

[image]